# How to use GoogleSheets API in .Net core?

Tags: c#, google-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to create and edit google sheets using c# in ASP.net CORE.

Currently I can edit a sheet, using this code:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.
        FromStream(new FileStream("Google/client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open)).
            CreateScoped(SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets);
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "just a test"
        });
// service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRangeNames, spreadsheetId, rangeNames);
```

As you can see, I am using a service account.

In google's .NET Quickstart guide, they use this code:

```
UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
```

BUT, in .NET Core, the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker does not exist.
From what I understand, that is used to authenticate to a google account using Oauth2.

I also read somewhere here on SO that you cannot create a google sheet using the sheet api. You need to use the google drive api.
I used the google drive api (gain, authentication using a service account). I was able to create a file, but I don't know how to access it. I know I created a file because the example they give on their api has a little method that shows all the files in that service account.

Long story short:
Let's say I have a google account for the application. I want to use this account to create multiple sheets, using C# .NetCore .
I want those sheets to be editable only by certain people if possible. If not, only from the application. 
Everyone else shall have only view permission.

How can I do this? Is the service account useful for what I plan on doing? If not, how can I authenticate to the api with .Net Core?

Before you ask, yes, I searched (a lot) for a replacement for that GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker, but I cannot figure it out. I never used google apis and I am not a experienced programmer either. Still, using standard .NET code, all examples on google quickstart guides work. Why wouldn't they work in .NET Core?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker seems to use .Net Core unfriendly methods, but there are other ways of authentication.

First, you need your application's refresh token. If you have previously authorized with code, it will be located in `AppData\Roaming\GoogleCredentials\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user` (Open with your favorite text editor). Otherwise see [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#getting-access-keys-for-your-application) for getting your application refresh token.

Then you can simply authorize like so,

```
var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = tokenYouJustGot };
UserCredential credentials;
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("client_secret.json"))
{
    credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer()
        {
            ClientSecretsStream = stream
        }), "user", token);
}

var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
    ApplicationName = "Sample Application"
});
```

After getting your `SheetsService`, you can proceed to make and edit spreadsheets.
For example, to create a new spreadsheet, you can do `var sheet = service.Spreadsheets.Create(new Spreadsheet());`